# Accessing array items

Tags: python, spyder

I've got a list that is one dimensional that I need separated by spaces.   I am running this script in spyder for ubuntu running on parallels on Mac OS 10.8.

what I'm getting is this:

```
print poly    
Output: [array([ 0.01322341,  0.07460202,  0.00832512])]

print poly[0]    
Output: [array([ 0.01322341,  0.07460202,  0.00832512])]

print poly[1]    
Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/parallels/.../RampEst.py", line 38, in <module>

    print poly[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The "..." is the rest of the file directory.

What I need is:

```
print poly[0]    
Output: 0.01322341

print poly[1]    
Output: 0.07460202

print poly[2]    
Output: 0.00832512
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the brackets in the right place in the output you're showing us? It seems very strange to me that `poly` and `poly[0]` are printing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Also, what is your `array` type? It's output doesn't match `array.array` from the standard library (which includes a "type" character such as 'd' for double precision floats). While this shouldn't matter, it might if the interface for the type is buggy.

Comment: Your title has **nothing** to do with the question.

Answer (score 4):

You are constructing your `list` objects in the wrong way. If you post where you're doing that it might be clear as to the actual problem.

You'll notice that the following:

```
mylist = [ 0.01322341,  0.07460202,  0.00832512]
mylist[0] # 0.01322341 
mylist[1] # 0.07460202 
mylist[2] # 0.00832512
```

Works fine. From what you're posted, you have a `list` of `array` types. When you access the `0` element you are retrieving the only `array` object in the list. If you can't change the structure of your list, this will work fine.

```
poly[0][0] # 0.01322341 
poly[0][1] # 0.07460202 
poly[0][2] # 0.00832512
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you first initialize poly? 
It seems that the array is within a list, which would make it the zeroth element of the list. Therefore, when you request poly[1] it fails.
To check if what I am saying is correct, do poly[0][0], poly[0][1] and poly[0][2]. If these return the numbers you want, then your poly is inside a list.